# How can I set varibales in an instance in Camunda after its creation in JUnit tests?

Tags: junit, camunda

I know that you can an instance when you create one as described [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.10/user-guide/process-engine/process-instance-modification/#process-instance-modification-in-junit-tests) in the documentation but when a process is created by a parent process then you are not in control of creating the instance anymore. How can I modify the instance in such scenario and set some variables in it ?

P.S. The variables that I want to set are set inside the delegates that are mocked obviously.

Answer (score 1):

OK, silly me.

turns out that RuntimeService first parameter can be executionId **or** processInstanceId

So

runtimeService.setVariable(processInstanceId, "variableName", "variableValue");